# Maintaining a ratio when splitting up data in python function

Tags: python, function, numpy

I have some data and I want to split it up into smaller groups that maintain a common ratio. I wrote a function that will take an input of two array and calculate the size ratio and then tell me the options for how many groups I can split it into (if all the groups are the same size), here is the function:

```
def cross_validation_group(train_data, test_data):
    import numpy as np
    from calculator import factors
    test_length = len(test_data)
    train_length = len(train_data)
    total_length = test_length + train_length
    ratio = test_length/float(total_length)
    possibilities = factors(total_length)
    print possibilities
    print possibilities[len(possibilities)-1] * ratio
    super_count = 0
    for i in possibilities:
        if i < len(possibilities)/2:
            pass
        else: 
            attempt = float(i * ratio)
            if attempt.is_integer():
                print str(i) + " is an option for total size with " +  str(attempt) + " as test size and " + str(i - attempt) + " as train size! This is with " + str(total_length/i) + " folds."
            else:
                pass
    folds = int(raw_input("So how many folds would you like to use? If no possibilities were given that would be sufficient, type 0: "))
    if folds != 0:
        total_size = total_length/folds
        test_size = float(total_size * ratio)
        train_size = total_size - test_size
        columns = train_data[0]
        columns= len(columns)
        groups = np.empty((folds,(test_size + train_size),columns))
        i = 0
        a = 0
        b = 0
        for j in range (0,folds):
            test_size_new = test_size * (j + 1)
            train_size_new = train_size * j
            total_size_new = (train_size + test_size) * (j + 1)
            cut_off = total_size_new - train_size
            p = 0
            while i < total_size_new:
                if i < cut_off:
                    groups[j,p] = test_data[a]
                    a += 1
                else:
                    groups[j,p] = train_data[b]
                    b += 1
                i += 1
                p += 1
        return groups
    else:
        print "This method cannot be used because the ratio cannot be maintained with equal group sizes other than for the options you were givens"
```

So my question is how can I make it so that a third input to the function that will be the number of folds and change the function around so that rather than iterating through to make sure that each group has the same amount with the right ratio, it will just have the right ratio, but varying sizes?

**Addition for @JamesHolderness**

So your method is almost perfect, but here is one issue:

with lengths 357 and 143 with 9 folds, this is the returning list:

```
[(39, 16), (39, 16), (39, 16), (39, 16), (39, 16), (39, 16), (39, 16), (39, 16), (39, 16)]
```

now when you add up the columns, you get this: `351 144`

the 351 is fine because it's less than 357, but the 144 doesn't work because it is greater than 143! The reason for this is that 357 and 143 are lengths of arrays, so the 144th row of that array does not exist...

Comment: Do you mean that you want to cross-validate with a varying training set? This sounds kind of iffy statistically? Is it usually done in practice?

Comment: yes this is for cross validation. No, this is supposed to test the similarity between a test and training set to check if there might be something in the test data that is not in the training data. Normally cross-validation is done on just that one training set and this could be applied their too, rather than two arrays, you would give the column in the training array and the training array and it would do it that way.

Comment: If your two arrays are of sizes `m` and `n` and the irreducible fraction of `m` divided by `n` is `p/q`, then `m = k*p` and `n = k*q`. Once you have `k`, any [partition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of it will lead you to a split of your original data that keeps the ratio of elements. Let me know if you need me to elaborate.

Comment: Ah good old number theory...Unfortunately that is limiting. I want to be able to have any number of groups, even a number that doesn't evenly divide because the sizes can be different as long as the ratio from one dataset to the other is consistant. Does that make sense?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's an algorithm that I think might work for you.

You take the test_length and train_length and divide by their GCD to get the ratio as a simple fraction. You take the numerator and denominator and you add them together, and that is the size factor for your groups.

For example if the ratio is 3:2, the size of each group must be a multiple of 5.

You then take the total_length and divide it by the number of folds to get the ideal size for the first group, which may well be a floating point number. You find the largest multiple of 5 that is less than or equal to that, and that is your first group.

Subtract that value from your total, and divide by by folds-1 to get the ideal size for the next group. Again find the largest multiple of 5, subtract the from the total, and continue until you have calculated all the groups.

Some example code:

```
total_length = test_length + train_length          
divisor = gcd(test_length,train_length)
test_multiple = test_length/divisor
train_multiple = train_length/divisor
total_multiple = test_multiple + train_multiple 

# Adjust the ratio if there isn't enough data for the requested folds
if total_length/total_multiple < folds:
  total_multiple = total_length/folds
  test_multiple = int(round(float(test_length)*total_multiple/total_length))
  train_multiple = total_multiple - test_multiple

groups = []
for i in range(folds,0,-1):
  float_size = float(total_length)/i
  int_size = int(float_size/total_multiple)*total_multiple
  test_size = int_size*test_multiple/total_multiple
  train_size = int_size*train_multiple/total_multiple
  test_length -= test_size    # keep track of the test data used
  train_length -= train_size  # keep track of the train data used
  total_length -= int_size
  groups.append((test_size,train_size))

# If the test_length or train_length are negative, we need to adjust the groups
# to "give back" some of the data.
distribute_overrun(groups,test_length,0)
distribute_overrun(groups,train_length,1)
```

This has been updated to keep track of the size used from each group (test and train) but not worry if we use too much initially.

Then at the end, if there's any overrun (i.e. `test_length` or `train_length` have gone negative), we distribute that overrun back into the groups by decrementing the appropriate side of the ratio in as many items as it takes to bring the overrun back to zero.

The `distribute_overrun` function is included below.

```
def distribute_overrun(groups,overrun,part):
    i = 0
    while overrun < 0:
      group = list(groups[i])
      group[part] -= 1
      groups[i] = tuple(group)
      overrun += 1
      i += 1
```

At the end of that, groups will be a list of tuples containing the test_size and train_size for each group.

If that sounds like the sort of thing you want, but you need me to expand on the code example, just let me know.

Comment: Almost perfect!!! It works great in most situations, the only issue is if the fraction cannot simplify it returns all tuples as `(0,0)` except for the last one, which is just the original numbers. Is there any thing I could add to the function that would make it slightly break the ratio if the ratio is impossible as such?

Comment: also add `total_length = train_length + test_length` in the beginning, you didn't define `total_length`

Comment: I was using the `total_length` from your original code, but have added that to the example to clarify. Also updated the answer with some additional code to adjust the ratio if there isn't enough data. I should add that if your data doesn't divide evenly by the number of folds requested, you're going to have some data left over in the end.

Comment: yes I do know that, but unfortunately not every number of folds will work for every two datasets. The only one thing wrong right now is that when it readjusts the numbers and ratio slightly, occassionally one of the outputs will add to a total number greater than previously. This would be using a row that doesn't exist. i have been messing around, but making it always stay below the original doesn't seem to be working...

Comment: I'm not sure I'm understanding you. Can you give some example values where that occurs. I just mean test_length, train_length and number of folds.

Comment: I just added an extra thing for you in the question with a detailed explanation!

Comment: Thanks, that makes perfect sense. I've further adjusted the algorithm to take that into account. This means the ratios won't always match, but they shouldn't overrun now.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!! I have been trying to get that algorithm for two months! I get most of it, but the last thing you just did, how does that make it possible to only alter if necessary and to alter it as little as possible while staying as close as possible to the ratio?

Comment: I'm not sure it's ideal, but it depends on your preference. It's keeping tracking of the available data in each set (train and test) and making sure it doesn't use more than what is left in each of them. But this means all the error accumulates in the last group. I'm not sure if you'd prefer it distributed more evenly. For example, with 5 folds, most groups are 29:71 but the last is 27:71. Would it be preferable having two being 28:71?

Comment: it is preferred to maintain the ratio over maintaining the rows! so yes

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29751/discussion-between-james-holderness-and-ryan-saxe)

Answer (score 3):

In another question the author wanted to do a similar cross-validation as yours. Please, [take a look to this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16109485/832621). Working out that answer to your problem, it would be like:

```
import numpy as np
# in both train_data the first line is used for the cross-validation,
# and the other lines will follow, so you can add as many lines as you want
test_data = np.array([ 0.,  1.,  2.,  3.,  4.,  5.])
train_data  = np.array([[ 0.09,  1.9,  1.1,  1.5,  4.2,  3.1,  5.1],
                       [    3,    4,  3.1,   10,   20,    2,    3]])

def cross_validation_group( test_data, train_data):
    om1,om2 = np.meshgrid(test_data,train_data[0])
    dist = (om1-om2)**2
    indexes = np.argsort( dist, axis=0 )
    return train_data[:, indexes[0]]

print cross_validation_group( test_data, train_data )
# array([[  0.09,   1.1 ,   1.9 ,   3.1 ,   4.2 ,   5.1 ],
#        [     3 ,  3.1 ,     4 ,     2 ,    20 ,     3 ]])
```

You will have the `train_data` corresponding to the interval defined in `test_data`.

Comment: this is not at all what I want...My grouping works fine for something like this, but I need my function to take another variable that will be the amount of groups to make for the array and the sizes of the arrays can be different as long as they have the same ratio from training data to test data

Comment: so I think I missed your point. This one works for different sizes, but there is no variable telling the amount of groups (which is controlled by the test_data that you give...

Comment: basically I need another variable, x, where x = the number of groups. the number of rows can be different, but in each group there must be the same ratio of rows from the test_data and rows from the training data. This way there is no bias in the cross-validation

Comment: could you make available the input files or variables so that we can play with it? (using sth like Dropbox is convinient)

Comment: it's very important that this works on any kind of data. so I would say just throw in 2 numpy arrays, one being all 1s and the other being all 0s, each with the same amount of columns and mess around like that! It also makes it easy to see that it's mixing the rows from the separate arrays